# Will a 60W powered USB 3.0 Hub handle multiple (7-10) WD Passport 4TB Bus-powered Ext. HDDs?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

I have a Core i5 PC that is a dedicated Plex server and it has plenty of USB ports (for now) but I don't think the ports supply enough power for 4 or more 4tb ext. HDDs as I had 1 HDD die on me and lost all my files. I was looking into getting a powered USB hub to compensate for the power draw. A lot the reviewers on Amazon for these devices seem to either run into connection problems when hooking up multiple HDDs or they aren't using it in this manner. I was hoping for someone on here with experience connecting high amounts of Ext HDDs could recommend a viable option.

Comment: " I don't think the ports supply enough power for 4 or more 4tb ext. HDDs " Sure they do, what makes you think this is the cause of the hdd failure?

Comment: Maybe it isn't. I read something on another forum that suggested that this could happen. I still would like to get a nice powered hub to go beyond the 4 port/drive limitation. Do you personally use one with multiple ext HDDs without issue?

Comment: Better to install an add in pci usb card in the server if possible.

Comment: Why not just get powered external HDD's? That way the hub is really just passing data, not supplying power.

Comment: Haha, all answers I was trying to avoid the hassle of. So nobody knows of a high-powered USB Hub that can handle the draw of multiple Ext HDDs, huh? Shoot. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Plenty exist, but shopping recommendations are off topic and it really depends on your disks.  Also, using such hubs will cause bottlenecks on the USB interface. A PCI usb port which supports 10 watts (2 amps) per port would be a goid idea if its an option.

Comment: OP: If you could tell how much this drive consumes form USB cable, we probably will be able to give you some useful hints...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [research I just did](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lc6VdpaT_2g), WD "My Passport" 1/2/3/4GB portable external storage uses dedicated hard drives designed to have a USB-only interface, which doesn't need any SATA-USB or whatever bridges:

[image]

[image]

According to the nameplate, its power consumption is 0.39A at +5VDC supply. If this is true, **any properly-powered** external USB N-port hub must be capable of handling power for any number of these drives.

However, it is absolutely unclear whether this "0.39A" number is for sustained operation mode, or includes peak inrush currents during spin-up. It is known that rotation-based HDD can have substantial current draw during spin-up or intensive search that might cause weaker USB ports to sag their VBUS leading to storage malfunction and even catastrophic failures by messing all service data.

More, the WD drive nor the product itself do not carry USB-IF certification logo, nor the USB certification is listed in [any user manual](https://www.wd.com/content/dam/wdc/website/downloadable_assets/eng/user_manual/4779-705155.pdf). Therefore, something must be USB non-compliant if they can't pass the USB-IF certification. Therefore, all bets must be off if counting on long reliable service, especially from many drives in one cluster.